# Error 'boost::hash_combine': recursive function template definition after Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 installed

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, visual-studio-2015, precompiled-headers

After my Visual studio 2015 updated from Update 1 to Update 2 my project doesn't compiling. I get an error

> 'boost::hash_combine': recursive function template definition
>   boost-1_60\boost\functional\hash\hash_fwd.hpp(25): note: see declaration of 'boost::hash_combine'

Why does it happen?
Removing or moving `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>` from `stdafx.h` solved the problem. But how can I don't move it from there?

```
//stdafx.h
#ifndef STDAFX_H
#define STDAFX_H

#include <map>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/back_inserter.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

#endif
```

-

```
//main.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"

class IByteStream
{
public:
    explicit IByteStream(const std::string &s)
        : _basicArraySource(s.data(), s.size())
        , _stream(_basicArraySource)
        , _iArchive(_stream)
    {
    }

    template<class T>
    IByteStream &operator >> (T &data) { _iArchive >> data; return *this; }

private:
    typedef boost::iostreams::basic_array_source<char> BasicArraySource;
    typedef boost::iostreams::stream<BasicArraySource> Stream;
    typedef boost::archive::binary_iarchive BinaryIArchive;

    boost::iostreams::basic_array_source<char> _basicArraySource;
    boost::iostreams::stream<BasicArraySource> _stream;
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive _iArchive;
};

struct S1
{
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned) {}
};

struct S2
{
    std::map<int, std::map<int, S1>> mp;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned) { ar & mp; }
};

struct S3
{
    std::vector<S2> v;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned) { ar & v; }
};

inline void parse(IByteStream &ibs) {}

template<class T, class... TT>
void parse(IByteStream &ibs, T &t, TT&... tt)
{
    ibs >> t;
    parse(ibs, tt...);
}

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    IByteStream ibs(str);
    S3 s3;
    parse(ibs, s3);
}
```

[Test1.zip](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=69073313277883963480)

Comment: Can you do the work to produce a [MCVE]?  I doubt *every* line above is required to produce that error.

Comment: @yakk if remove something error will not be.

Comment: if you remove `ar & mp;` in `serialize` in `struct S2` it will not produce the error?  If you move the precompiled header into `main.cpp` it will not produce the error?  If you make `IByteStream::operator>>` just `return *this;` the error goes away?

Comment: @yakk error goes away in all three cases